# Trouble in passing interface as an argument

Tags: typescript

I am new to TypeScript (Version 1.8.10). I have this code;

```
interface SomeInterface {
    label: string;  
}

function interfaceTester(arg: SomeInterface){
    console.log("This is the interface tester's argument : ", arg.label);
}

//working
interfaceTester({label:"Label value alone"});
```

But, when I tried this code, with an additional parameter,

```
interfaceTester({someOneElse: 45, label:"Label value with one extra argument;"});
```

it is **not working**; It throws compile error;

Instead when I tried the *same*(I believe so) this way :

```
let obj = {someOneElse: 45, label:"Label value with one extra argument;" };

interfaceTester(obj);
```

**is working fine**; I could compile and execute it.

Am I doing anything wrong? Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   let obj = {someOneElse: 45, label:"Label value with one extra argument;" };
```

while building compiler treats the obj as of type **any** rather specific type of the interface (SomeInterface). This assumes the compiler to treat the variable as dynamic.

To restrict this you should specify the data type.

```
 let obj: SomeInterface = { someOneElse: 45, label: "Label value with one extra argument;" };
```

This will give the build error.

Answer (score 0):

That is the expected behavior. You can solve it using a casting:

```
interfaceTester(<SomeInterface>{someOneElse: 45, label:"Label value with one extra argument;"});
```

You can find documentation about why it works this way [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3755).

Comment: thanks for the answer and that works fine. But I am still confused on the fact that, in either of the cases (**working** or not working), I haven't specified anything about the interface (`SomeInterface`). Only difference is that, in working case, it is assigned to a variable. Then how the compiler is aware about this (`SomeInterface`) interface?